# How to build to different version of the site for mobile

Tags: php, mobile

Yoohoo.
I want to build two versions of my site for mobile and tablets.
1. less than 7 inch
2. more than 7 inch

Do you know any LIB in php that provides this information?

1. How do I detect in php what is the screen size?
2. How do I know that this is actually a mobile and not desktop client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with CSS 3 `@media` queries.

#### Media Queries for Standard Devices

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

#### More info: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks, but don't you think it would be better to detect that in the server side? Why should I take all the content from the cms database? in the server side I can just pull 100 words instead 1500 words.

Comment: Screensize is in the client side. That is the reason. And while truncating contents, we depend on CSS and not on Server Side. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Again these days you can fine firefox extension that can be used to simulate device in a desktop.

The Following code detects if its mobile browser or not

```
<?php

$mobile_browser = '0';

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}    

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser = 0;
}

if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
   // do something
}
else {
   // do something else
}   

?>
```

Code was taken from http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php

Comment: Nothing about screen size there

Comment: @SexyMF, See my updated answer. And for screen size you can refer to the answer by Praveen Kumar in this question